# $(a,b)=1$ implies $R/(ab)$ isomorphic to $R/(a) \oplus R/(b)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

If $R$ is a PID and $a,b$ belong to $R$ and are relatively prime, then $R/(ab)$ is isomorphic to $R/(a) \oplus R/(b)$ (direct sum). I can't find this problem in Internet. Any idea?

Comment: Google "Chinese Remainder Theorem"

Answer (score 2):

The more general result doesn't require $R$ to be a PID, nor even in integral domain. It is the following:

> Let $R$ be a commutative ring, $I, J$ ideals of $R$ such that $I+J=R$. Then $I\cap J=IJ$, and the mapping
>   \begin{align*}R/(I\cap J)&\longrightarrow R/I\times R/J\\
> x\bmod I\cap J&\longmapsto (x\bmod I,x\bmod J)
> \end{align*}
>   is a ring isomorphism.

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* Consider the map $R \to  R/(a)\times R/(b)$ given by $x \mapsto (x \bmod a, x \bmod b)$. Prove that when  $a$ and $b$ are relatively prime, this map is surjective and its kernel is $(ab)$.